# berkleybd Java Edition API about openbatabase

Tags: java, api, berkeley-db-je

I read the document of "Getting Started with Berkeley DB Java Edition"on the oracle library.I found this API:

Database
openDatabase(Transaction txn, String databaseName, DatabaseConfig dbConfig)
Opens, and optionally creates, a Database.

but when I use in my application I found this:

public Database openDatabase(Transaction var1, String var2, String var3, DatabaseConfig var4) throws DatabaseException, FileNotFoundException 
{
    return new Database(DatabaseConfig.checkNull(var4).openDatabase(this.dbenv, var1 == null?null:var1.txn, var2, var3));
    }

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHeVZ.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Dyz.jpg)
there are four parameters not three, I don't know what's going on ...
someone help me please ,thank you

Comment: Don't use images. Include the relevant text in your question.

Comment: @Kayaman I edit again

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have misused the two products:
Berkeley DB (C Edition) and 
Berkeley DB Java Edition.

Both provide Java access APIs,

(1) Java API of **com.sleepycat.db**.Environment#openDatabase() for Berkeley DB (C Edition)   -- 4 parameters

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_05/html/java/com/sleepycat/db/Environment.html#openDatabase-com.sleepycat.db.Transaction-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-com.sleepycat.db.DatabaseConfig-

(2) Java API of **com.sleepycat.je**.Environment#openDatabase() for Berkeley DB Java Edition  -- 3 parameters

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/je/Environment.html#openDatabase-com.sleepycat.je.Transaction-java.lang.String-com.sleepycat.je.DatabaseConfig-